# Counting with AHK, Letters

Tags: autohotkey

I have been doing some recent experimentation with AHK, an interpreted automation scripting language, that can do tasks such as window move, mouse move, save and log info for files and I have found it very useful. I wanted to make a script that could sort of count, but with characters and symbols, a password list generator. As I need one for my attempts as a white hat.

```
;list of characters here
send, aaaaa
;then
send, aaaab
```

using a method like this I would very much appreciate help on the matter, thank you!

Comment: I didn't quite understand anything, especially this sentence: *" I wanted to make a script that could sort of count, but with characters and symbols, a password list generator."* Do you want to create a password generator? Do you want to count characters (from different character classes) in a given password? What does your script (which simply sends some `a`s and `b`s) have to with all that? Please invest some time in **rephrasing everything**! Read your question and ask yourself: **Can someone unfamiliar with my problem understand it?**

Comment: Looks like he wants to create a "Brute Force" password generator with AHK. For whatever reason. Smells dodgy tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a brute force kind of function, you could try this one:

```
BruteForce(Chars, Min, Max, Prefix, Stage)
{
   Loop, Parse, Chars
   {
      If (Stage >= Min-1)
         FileAppend, % Prefix A_loopField "`n", BruteForce.txt ;you could replace the line with: Send % Prefix A_loopField
      If (Stage < Max-1)
         BruteForce(Chars, Min, Max, Prefix A_LoopField, Stage + 1)
   }
}

BruteForce("abc", 1, 2, "", 0) ;this would create every possible combination of the letters abc (min length 1, max length 2)
```

The result is stored in the file BruteForce.txt