# Autohotkey - Letter cycling

Tags: autohotkey, modulo

I am a Math student, and I know modulo arithmetic which will likely help.

I want to code in Autohotkey, or autoit, on key click I want to run a sequence of typing commands, such as:

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

...

<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

etc.

I want to cycle through the letters all the way to

<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

> I want to generate all 12 length permutations of the letters `a-z` separated by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I'll put up work as I make it, any tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you just want to print out all possible combinations?

Comment: You know 12 to the 8th power is 430 million, right?

Comment: You want brute-force attack against a password dialog?

Comment: What are trying you to achieve? Btw: Bruteforcing a GUI dialog is way slow. You'd be better off extrapolating the hash and using a fast language (not AHK!) to brute-force against it.

Comment: What makes you think that modulo would help?

Comment: @Xenobiologist All possible permutations you mean, and yes. Combinations treat `aab` the same as `aba` or `baa`.

Comment: @Dennis_E they were just presentations, I meant 12 character length, and you got that mixed up, it is options^variables, here it is 26^12= 9.5428957e+16

Comment: @Forivin Since I imagine I could count numerically, and using modulo arithematic, I could move from `z` to `a` modulo 26.

Comment: @Katie So, it's even worse. If you generate 1 permutation each millisecond, then 26^12 will take you 3 million years. Good luck with that!

Comment: @Katie Then I don't understand why you want to generate 26^12 permutations if you know it can't be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pretty much same question was asked 2 weeks ago: [Counting with AHK, Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707231/counting-with-ahk-letters/25819129#25819129)
But I will gladly answer it again:
(click the link from above for a comment-less example, it got pretty messy here)

```
BruteForce(Chars, Min, Max, Prefix:="", Stage:=0) { ;function header
   Loop, Parse, Chars ;We loop through the character string that we are gonna pass to this function
   {
      If (Stage >= Min-1) { ;explained in the second if block
           ;Prefix: our last generated string (at the first iteration AAAAAAAAAAA (11 As))
           ;A_LoopField: contains current character of the "Chars" string that we are looping through
           ;"{Enter}": to tell SendInput to send an Enter after the Prefix and the current char
         SendInput % Prefix A_loopField "{Enter}" ;AAAAAAAAAAA A {Enter}
      }
      If (Stage < Max-1) { 
           ;at this point it get really tricky
           ;it's kinda hard to explain what exactly happens here
           ;and at the same time pretty selfexplainatory if you simply know the used AHK commands/keywords

           ;Basically what happens here is, the function is going to call itself again without leaving the loop
           ;increasing the state step by step (everytime we get here) until we reach (in this case) 12-1 so 11
           ;during the first "iteration" (in this case) we will be adding an A to the prefix parameter everytime the function re-calls itself
           ;when it reached 11, then it generated the string AAAAAAAAAAA (11 As)
           ;since the is at this point the expression state >= Min-1 (we passed a 12 for Min) is true
           ;we will output the the string + the current char (A) in the if block above
           ;then the second if statement will fail 
           ;and the loop of the current function call will go into it's second iteration
           ;and output again 11 As and our second character (B)
           ;etc etc until the loop is over, then the last function call is over and it will go to the one from before... 
           ;as I said... really hard to explain. to understnad it you are best of with simply going through the code like it would be executed and maybe take some notes of what has happened in each iteration
         BruteForce(Chars, Min, Max, Prefix A_LoopField, Stage + 1)
      }
   }
}

F1:: ;hotkey is F1
    BruteForce("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 12, 12) ;this would send possible combination of capital letters (min length 12, max length 12)
    ;you can change the min length and max length, as well as the character string however you want
Return
```

And here is a different approach that would give a more sorted output if the min and max length are not the same:

```
Generate(prefix, len, chars) {
    If (StrLen(prefix) = len)
        SendInput % prefix " "
    If (StrLen(prefix) < len)
        Loop, Parse, chars
            Generate(prefix A_LoopField, len, chars) 
}

BruteForce(chars, minLen, maxLen) {
    curLen := minLen
    Loop % maxLen-minLen+1 {
        Generate("", curLen, chars)
        curLen++
    }
}

F1::
   BruteForce("abc", 2, 3)
Return
```

Output would be: `aa ab ac ba bb bc ca cb cc aaa aab aac aba abb abc aca acb acc baa bab bac bba bbb bbc bca bcb bcc caa cab cac cba cbb cbc cca ccb ccc`

Comment: @Katie Well, "API" implies that there is a programming interface, so if that's true, it's probably possible, but I couldn'T predict how hard it's gonna be. If it doesn't have an interface, then you'll have to do some kind of code injection which involves a lot of reverse-engineering and requires advanced asm knowledge. This is pretty much as difficult as it could get.. You are probably best of with AHK's ControlSetText, ControlSend and maybe even ControlClick or SendMessage with "BM_CLICK".